# Dell XPS 15 suspend and hibernate problems

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate

I have the 2022 model of the XPS 15 and have installed Ubuntu 22.04 (with kernel 5.19 to resolve audio issues).

I'm having a few different issues with both suspend and hibernate (required because the hardware only supports s2idle and it drains the battery insanely fast - I've already changed from RAID to ACHI based on other posts).

The first problem: suspend doesn't seem to put the system into a remotely low power state - if I leave the laptop unplugged in suspend overnight, the battery will be *totally* dead in the morning - it seems to drain as much power in suspend as it does awake. I have checked that it is entering suspend when I close the lid (through dmesg and journalctl).

The second problem: I set up suspend then hibernate to resolve this issue - it seems to attempt to enter the hibernate state (from the journalctl) but *doesn't* actually hibernate - in the morning the laptop is still warm and when I open it up, the keyboard and screen backlights immediately come on (though the machine then hangs).

Some details:
The system has 32GB RAM and 40GB swap space (that is almost never used). The disk is encrypted with luks, both the root partition and the swap partition (within the same luks, which I believe may cause me trouble down the road, but one step at a time)

```
uname -a
Linux laptop-xps 5.19.0-051900rc3-generic #202206192130 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Jun 19 21:34:04 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I run docker on the laptop (sometimes with containers running, sometimes not), other than that I don't run anything particularly interesting

The output of journalctl from when it entered suspend until I rebooted (last night to this morning).

```
sudo journalctl --since "22-08-22 22:40:03"
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps systemd-logind[1480]: Lid closed.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: received input layer event "button/lid LID close"
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps gnome-shell[3157]: Initialized single buffered shadow fb for eDP-1
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: rule from /etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid matched
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps systemd-logind[1480]: Suspending, then hibernating...
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps acpid[16600]: executing action "/etc/acpi/laptop-lid.sh button/lid LID close"
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.6679] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: action exited with status 0
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.6680] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: 1 total rule matched
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.6682] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: completed input layer event "button/lid LID close"
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.6683] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps ModemManager[1526]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps evolution[11286]: Network disconnected.  Forced offline.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps dbus-daemon[1445]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=1447 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps dbus-daemon[1445]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps kernel: wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from d4:5d:64:c5:ce:0c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps update-notifier[5812]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps update-notifier[5812]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=d4:5d:64:c5:ce:0c reason=3 locally_generated=1
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.8829] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.8830] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps avahi-daemon[1443]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9cd4:d625:f2ad:b306 on wlp0s20f3.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps avahi-daemon[1443]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 with address fe80::9cd4:d625:f2ad:b306.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps avahi-daemon[1443]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps gnome-shell[3157]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.9222] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.9223] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.9223] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.9224] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps avahi-daemon[1443]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.114 on wlp0s20f3.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps avahi-daemon[1443]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.114.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps avahi-daemon[1443]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps systemd-resolved[1346]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set default route setting: no
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps systemd-resolved[1346]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Aug 22 22:40:03 zacknewsham-xps NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1661222403.9738] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp0s20 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps wpa_supplicant[1484]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp0s20f3 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Starting Suspend; Hibernate if not used for a period of time...
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd-sleep[16689]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Aug 22 22:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.008 seconds
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.347 seconds) done.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: nvme nvme0: 20/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd-resolved[1346]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: input device has been disconnected, fd 28
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps bluetoothd[1912]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps gnome-shell[3157]: Could not release device '/dev/input/event27' (13,91): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.DeviceNotTaken: Device not taken
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: thermal thermal_zone13: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps anacron[16813]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2022-08-23
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Starting Daily dpkg database backup service...
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps anacron[16813]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps anacron[16813]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: received netlink event " 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: 0 total rules matched
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: completed netlink event " 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: received netlink event " 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: 0 total rules matched
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps acpid[1440]: completed netlink event " 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd-sleep[16689]: System returned from sleep state.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps bluetoothd[1912]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: PM: suspend exit
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: cups-browsed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Stopped Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: cups.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: cups.path: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: cups.socket: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Closed CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: PM: Image not found (code -16)
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Starting CUPS Scheduler...
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: dpkg-db-backup.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Finished Daily dpkg database backup service.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps audit[17065]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=17065 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd[1]: Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1661229604.947:226): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=17065 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps audit[17073]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=17073 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1661229604.959:227): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=17073 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
Aug 23 00:40:04 zacknewsham-xps systemd-sleep[16689]: Entering sleep state 'hibernate'...
-- Boot b6211a86252d4b2fbf33f363e22fe48b --
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with s2idle. The solution for me was to set

```
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/ec_no_wake
```

to

```
Y
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped a little (drain overnight dropped to around 6%/hour) - but this is still much higher than I'd expect

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I reinstalled Ubuntu fresh, and *all* my problems went away, starting from the issue with the bass speakers not working.

Now suspend works properly, and it draws about 1%/hour, hibernate "just works" - including automatic hibernate when the battery is almost flat (which was a nice surprise).

I've now reinstalled everything I previously had working (I thought that perhaps docker or the fingerprint reader were the source of my woes, but no - everything works)

I only did two things differently when I reinstalled:

1. I selected the "install updates" option
2. I made sure during installation there was a large enough swap partition for hibernate, rather than adding it later. This is harder than it sounds when using full disk encryption because the installer doesn't give you the option to specify the swap size, however a little modal pops up asking if you're sure about the changes, at which point you can open up gparted and resize the 1GB swap partition to whatever you want